# Manipulating/changing adressbar link

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting, address-bar

I am out of my own "ideas" going through this.

I have a album viewer. When you click next I want the adressbar to hang with it, e.g if you start on ?photoid=1, and click next (next picture appends and stuff), and then i want it to say ?photoid=2.

Now I cant make it say ?photoid=2 without changing/manipulating, and this you cant do without HTML5.

I have made a script in HTML5 that works fine, but then I need to take care of those who dont have HTML5(only chrome, ff4 etc supports html5)
Made the script from this( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history )

I thought of adding #photoid=2 so, ?photoid=1#photoid=2 and then check if theres anything in # then use that instead of the $_GET.. But apparently you cannot do that as # is client side handled and never sent to the server.

So what should I then do?

Any suggestions please to make a workaround this? I checked facebook, what they did to IE users, and I could hear that it "clicked" (the annoying click sound from IE) twice.. the first was to get to the next picture, the second click sound changed the adressbar?!(how?).

And then I also thought hey, html5 is only supported in ff4, and I got ff3.6, and they manipulate the adress bar url when you browse through the album photos, exactly like how I wanted (and what I have written for but it only works in Chrome and ff4..?). How could they do that?

Answer (score 1):

The hash is the only way to change out the url bar without automatically refreshing the page you're on. That's why it's an anchor tag (the hash) historically. Everything else tells your browser to go to a different page. If you don't want it to forward, throw in a hash and then read that hash with javascript and do what you want that way. It's easy with jQuery, or you could dig into [Asual's swf address js library](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) or [jQuery's Hash Tag Change Listener](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) plugin if you want to use your browsers back/forward button to go through your history states.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if understood your quite right, but here's what I came up with for a similar problem.

Why don't you just set the url by editing the location.hash just like you said to make it look something like this: *www.mydomain.com/photos/#photoid=2*.

Now when somebody calls this url the browser will try to load www.mydomain.com/photos/ and will get the necessary markup but not the photo and what you can do now is read the location.hash (which will return photoid=2) and load the picture via AJAX by sending a request to the server with a path like "www.mydomain.com/photos/" + location.hash